# How to use xargs with cross platform commands

Tags: bash, cross-platform

I want to generate a one-liner in bash that has the following structure:

```
generate-url.sh | xargs `cross-platform-open`
```

where `cross-platform-open` should be a one-liner that either runs `xdg-open` or `open` depending on the platform.

I was able to run run this cross platform command by using the line

```
if [ `uname` == "Linux" ] ; then `xdg-open` ; else `open` ; fi
```

and it works fine for my purposes. However, when I want to throw this into the above line, bash starts complaining (obviously because the inner grave accent (`) characters are breaking the execution block of the outer ones). I tried using `eval` instead but with no luck. Could somebody please help me with this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `generate-url.sh`?

Comment: It is an url string. e.g. "http://www.example.com/912EC803"

Comment: Use `$()` instead of backticks to run commands. They nest properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need evaluate the conditional to produce the name of an executable, because `xargs` is going to call the executable:

```
opener() {
  if [ $(uname) == Linux ]; then echo xdg-open; else echo open; fi;
}
generate-url.sh | xargs $(opener)
```

Above, I used `$(...)` instead of the long-obsolete backtick syntax. Although backticks are still supported, they should be avoided; for one thing, they don't nest so you cannot use them insert the definition `opener` directly, as you can with `$(...)` :

```
generate-url.sh | xargs $(if [ $(uname) == Linux ]; then echo xdg-open; else echo open; fi;)
```

Comment: Aha, so the solution was to 1) use $() instead of `` and 2) and most importantly, to echo the command text instead of running it. I think you should emphasise those aspects so future users won't pass your answer.